# javascript function if ,else conditions

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am new to programming, I have created following Javascript function from scratch. But, it not executing correctly.It has some errors,but,I can't clear the errors.please help me,

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
            var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
            if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "checkbox")
            {
                var ItemCode = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                var ItemName = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                var Unit = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                var Price = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
                var StockQty = row.cells[5].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtICode.ClientID %>').value = ItemCode;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtIName.ClientID %>').value = ItemName;
                document.getElementById('<%=DropDownUnit.ClientID %>').value = Unit;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtPrice.ClientID %>').value = Price;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtStockQty.ClientID %>').value = StockQty;
                return false;

            }
           else (row.cells[0].innerHTML != checkbox)
            {
                 var ItemCode = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
                var ItemName = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
                var Unit = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                var Price = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
                var StockQty = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtICode.ClientID %>').value = ItemCode;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtIName.ClientID %>').value = ItemName;
                document.getElementById('<%=DropDownUnit.ClientID %>').value = Unit;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtPrice.ClientID %>').value = Price;
                document.getElementById('<%=TxtStockQty.ClientID %>').value = StockQty;
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `else` doesn't take any conditions, it's just `else { ... }` as in if the previous value was `false` in the condition above it will execute the code inside `else`. `else if(..) { ... }` accepts a condition, but based on what it appears you are trying to do you won't want to use that.

Comment: `else (row.cells[0].innerHTML != checkbox)` should be `else if ...`

Answer (score -1):

If you, in fact, want to test a second condition if the first is false then,

`else (row.cells[0].innerHTML != checkbox)`

should be:

`else if(row.cells[0].innerHTML != checkbox)`

but your `else` condition is the same as your `if` condition (except that you forgot quotes around `checkbox` in the `else`), so if `row.cells[0].innerHTML == "checkbox"`, then your code will never hit the `else` branch. **You most-likely don't want a condition at all in the else.**

Also, if your function heads down one of these two paths (true/false) and they both return `false` then it seems that either your are using that to exit the function, which would be unnecessary since your function terminates after the `if` statement anyway or you want the `false` to always be the return value, which doesn't make any sense.

Lastly, about half of the code in your true branch is identical to the code in your false branch. That code needs to run no matter what, so just write it once, outside of both branches and let your `if` branches just worry about what's different under each circumstance (DRY: "Don't Repeat Yourself" is a best-practice in any programming language.)

```
function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {

    var ItemCode, ItemName, Unit,Price, StockQty;
    var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;

    if (row.cells[0].innerHTML == "checkbox") {
        ItemCode = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        ItemName = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
        Unit = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
        Price = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
        StockQty = row.cells[5].innerHTML;

    } else {
        ItemCode = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
        ItemName = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
        Unit = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
        Price = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
        StockQty = row.cells[4].innerHTML;
    }

    document.getElementById('<%=TxtICode.ClientID %>').value = ItemCode;
    document.getElementById('<%=TxtIName.ClientID %>').value = ItemName;
    document.getElementById('<%=DropDownUnit.ClientID %>').value = Unit;
    document.getElementById('<%=TxtPrice.ClientID %>').value = Price;
    document.getElementById('<%=TxtStockQty.ClientID %>').value = StockQty;

}
```

Comment: It probably should be `else`, `checkbox` isn't defined. It appears OP just forgot to make that into a string.

Comment: Sorry, I did some mistakes. Mistakenly I typed else instead else if

Comment: I want to use the same Javascript function when clicking SELECT button from two GridView .The first GridView has a CheckBox field in [0] th column and second GridView Does not.

Comment: @Ram And, your question is what?

Comment: I want call this JavaScript function from Gridview(Select button).And check it has a Checkbox field in first column and execute if condition otherwise else condition will be executed.

Comment: @Ram So again, I ask, what exactly is your question?